# How to debug in VI

Tags: php, debugging, vi

Using vim 7.1, I recently heard you can debug php in VI.
But how?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to debugging vim script, vim -D is a first step.

More details in [Debugging Vim Scripts](http://www.troubleshootingwiki.org/Debugging_Vim_Scripts).

Answer (score 2):

See the link on using xdebug with vim that someone else posted for a full debugger, but as an extra tip you can do this from vim to run syntax check on the current PHP script:

```
:!php -l %
```

I have this assigned to my F5 key by putting this in my .vimrc file (in your home(~) directory):

```
nmap <F5> :! php5 -l %<CR>
```